# Is this possible to have placeholder in routes prefix?

Tags: symfony, url-routing

I've read the [Symfony docs about routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) but didn't find any info about how to include placeholders in the route prefix. Could someone give me advice?

I try to create prefix like:

```
resource: "@JobsBundle/Resources/config/routing/jobs.yml"
  prefix:   /{culture}/jobs
  defaults: {culture: en}
```

but I am getting error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The
>   "jobs" route has some missing mandatory parameters ("culture")

Comment: Lack of context and effort, maybe?

Comment: No. I read all docs about routing, didn't find this info.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta Probably you didn't read this docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html and gave me a minus just because my question is short :/

Comment: That's part of my reason, yes. Context, man, context! Edit your question to include that, and I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: Ok now I understand. Question edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using placeholders in route prefixes is not possible in versions 2.0.x. You have to wait until version 2.1 gets released.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting the defaults value with the routes in JobsBundle/Resources/config/routing/jobs.yml ?

Comment: I'll try and probably it will work but I hope that I can avoid repeating properties like this (defauls, requirements).It seems that default property in prefix just not work.